# how to stop Chrome running ActionResult when the URL is selected in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I am writing an ASP-MVC5 c#.net application. when running the development code on my machine using debug build and Chrome as my browser, Chrome appears to be initiating the ActionResult as soon as the URL is selected in the browser URL address (i.e. not waiting for me to generate the GET request) is this a feature of Chrome and if so can I turn it off as it is REALLY ANNOYING. (the particular Action sends a text message so it is costing me a fortune if it fires every time I scroll past it in the auto-suggested list)  EDGE does not seem to have the same behaviour - I haven't tested all the other browsers

Comment: Send another page/action as the start page and start debugging. So VS will open that page and when you want to execute your text sending action method, call that by changing the url in the browser

Answer (score 0):

decorating the ActionResult with [HttpGet] seemed to do the trick. I still wonder why Chrome fires the AR when no other browser does, and is it just because the webserver is running on the local machine???